# Ubuntu 15.10 / Xfce4 / Xubuntu ==> Whisker Menu graphically corrupt upon Save, recoverable via logout/login

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, whisker

Ubuntu 15.10 / Xfce4 / Xubuntu
==> Whisker Menu

- Applications menu reduces to a truncated white line without 
  clickable items upon Panel=>Edit Applications=>[Save]
- Need to logout/login to recover from this predicament

Is there an easy whiskermenu restart on the cmdline in order not
to have to log out?? I don't have casual login sessions and not
everything is suitable for a 'screen' session so I hope I can
avoid the logout/in charade for every manual update to the Whisker Menu.

[image: Screenshot of corrupted menu dialog with just a residual top line]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on panel (menu / applications). 
Choose Panel > Panel Preferences > Items
Select Whisker Menu and press the red X on the right (remove)
Then press + on the right for new item, select 'Applications Menu' and finally press 'Add'
Use the up and down arrows to position it where you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it out. In my system [X] is [-] (a red minus). But this does not solve the problem as visible in the screen dump. A white line is protruding to the right of the main menu and no items of the Applications list are clickable. The menu looks sane again after logging out and logging in.

Comment: try to reinstall without lost your config **sudo apt-get install --reinstall xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin**

Comment: I did this. The Applications menu was correct after a restart of the xfce4-panel via the commandline (kill,nohup, &). However, the blue whisker icon now is not present on the black top menu line (Panel) anymore. After logging out and in again, the Applications menu was OK (as expected), but the blue whisker icon is still missing [whiskericon](https://warosu.org/g/thread/50572805) ** (wrapper-1.0:12511): With: probably unrelated: WARNING **: No outputs have backlight property

Comment: For the Icon image I mean: http://lignux.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/whisker.png